# Creating Start Menu icons with sub folders

Tags: vbscript, subdirectory, startmenu

I am trying to create a VB script to create Icons for Microsoft Kodu as the Icons do not get created when deployed via Microsoft SCCM when using the system account (a real pain.)

I have had some advice from some friends on splitting up the folder creation tasks into two steps, one for "Microsoft Research" and the other for "Kodu Game Lab" but I am getting stuck on line 19, character 2 - I guessing I am making a clasic n00b mistake as I am fairly new to scripting!

Any suggestions?
Here is my script:

```
Dim shell, Objfso, allStartMenu, myShortcut, allProgramMenuMR, allProgramMenuKodu
Set Objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Tells script how to get to All Users Start Menu
allProgramMenu = shell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersPrograms")

'Tells script to check if Microsoft Research start menu folder exists and creates it if necessary.
allProgramMenuMR = allProgramMenu + "\\Microsoft Research"

if not Objfso.FolderExists (allProgramMenuMR) Then
    Objfso.CreateFolder (allProgramMenuMR)
End If

'Tells script to check if Kodu Game Lab start menu folder exists and creates it if necessary.
allProgramMenuKodu = allProgramMenu + allProgramMenuMR + "\\Kodu Game Lab"

if not Objfso.FolderExists (allProgramMenuKodu) Then
    Objfso.CreateFolder (allProgramMenuKodu)
End If

' Create Kodu Game Lab shortcut

Set myShortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(allProgramMenuKodu + allProgramMenuMR + "\\Kodu Game Lab.lnk")

myShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Kodu Game Lab\Boku.exe"
myShortcut.Arguments = "/NoUpdate /NoInstrumentation"
myShortcut.WorkingDirectory = ""
myShortcut.WindowStyle = 4
myShortcut.Description = "Launch Kodu Game Lab."
myShortcut.Save()


' Create Configure Kodu Game Lab shortcut

Set myShortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(allProgramMenuKodu + allProgramMenuMR + "\\Configure Kodu Game Lab.lnk")

myShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Kodu Game Lab\BokuPreBoot.exe" 
myShortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA Security\RSA Authentication Manager\prog\"
myShortcut.WindowStyle = 4
myShortcut.Description = "Launch Kodu Game Lab Configuration Utility"
myShortcut.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the parentheses on that line. You have two options:

1. On that line remove the ( ) because you are not setting a variable on that line. The ( ) is not required or
2. Change the line to read `newFolder = Objfso.CreateFolder(AllProgramMenuKodu)`